# Find minimum number of currency notes and values that sum to given amount array issue

Tags: javascript, arrays

when I try get this value 2316 its return [0,2,0,3,0,0,2,1,0,1] but I need get this out put [0,2,0,3,0,0,1,1,0,1] I think something wrong with my algorithm.

```
function findNoteAndCoins(salary) {
  var note = [5000,1000,500,100,50,20,10,5,2,1];
  var noteCount = new Array(10);
  noteCount = Array.from(noteCount, item => item || 0);

    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if (salary >= note[i]){
            noteCount[i]= salary / note[i];
            salary = salary % note[i];
        }
    }

   for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        if (noteCount[j] != 0){
            var count = noteCount[j];
        }
    }

  return noteCount.map(num => (num * 1).toFixed(0));  
}

findNoteAndCoins(2316);
```

Comment: `(1.6).toFixed(0) === "2";` - use `Math.floor`.

Comment: how should I apply this code segment ?

Comment: `noteCount[i] = Math.floor(salary / note[i]);`, you can also truncate, but it doesn't matter, as your values will always be positive. Btw, i don't understand your second loop at all, it seems completely pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert float number of notes to integer use `Math.trunc` or `Math.floor`: `Math.trunc(remaining / note)`

The whole code can look like:

```
function findNoteAndCoins(salary) {
  const notes = [5000, 1000, 500, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1];
  const notesCount = [];

  let remaining = salary;
  for (const note of notes) {
    if (salary >= note) {
      notesCount.push(Math.trunc(remaining / note));
      remaining = remaining % note;
    } else {
      notesCount.push(0);
    }
  }

  return notesCount;
}

console.log(findNoteAndCoins(2316));
```

and we can check that the `findNoteAndCoins` function works:

```
function findSalary(notesCount) {
  const notes = [5000, 1000, 500, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1];
  let salary = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < notesCount.length; i++) {
    salary += notesCount[i] * notes[i];
  }
  return salary;
}

console.log(findSalary(findNoteAndCoins(2316)) === 2316);
```